# iOS application hat bug?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I've been using the iOS application for 2 days now and still no hat.

**Is it some sort of bug?**

As a matter of fact, I'm writing this question on my phone.

Oh... Well, the text `use the iOS application` isn't very descriptive :|

Comment: [Must be caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: The hat descriptions are on purpose a little bit vague... that's part of the game....

Answer (score 2):

And [there it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/276253/lord-zsolt?tab=profile#winter-bash). You have your hat.

Using the app is not enough. According to the description:

> post, vote, edit, or comment with the iOS app

I guess you did now, so there you have your hat.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice they had a description as well.